# Styling string in ListView, Android Dev

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to style the resulting strings in a ListView.

I have a ListView layout, and the following onCreate method for the corresponding Activity.

```
private List<Address> addressList;

public class AddressesActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addresses);

    AddressDBHandler datasource = new AddressDBHandler(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Address> values = datasource.getAllAddresses();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

    .
    .
    .
```

The following is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/no_addresses" />
```

I was told to make the MyAdapter class as follows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Address> {

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Address> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    StringHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new StringHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (StringHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Address addressItem = getItem(position);
    Spanned format = Html.fromHtml("<br/><span color='red'>" + addressItem.getAddress() + "</span><br/>" +  addressItem.getName() + "<br/>");

    holder.txtTitle.setText(format);

    return row;
}

static class StringHolder
{
    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

My problem is in understanding :

```
holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1),
```

I am unsure what R.id.text1 is supposed to be.

I do have an additional question: Where are @android:id/empty and @android:id/list being referenced? Seems that they are default expectations from ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@android:id/empty and @android:id/list are predefined ids that are part of the android platform. ListActivities and ListFragments expect that these are present (or atleast that android:id/list is present) in the layout xml file. It means you don't have to bind these views from the xml yourself.

```
holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1)
```

The line above is basically finding a view in the xml file, and binding it to a variable for use in your activity (or in that case your list row).

The R.id.text1 is the id of the view in your layout. It's what you would set in the android:id field of your xml view.

e.g.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mytextview" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

In the case of your code above, you don't have a custom row layout, you are using a layout that is part of the android sdk (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1). This layout has a textview with the id android.R.id.text1.

So, if you want to customise your list row, create your own layout file. You can put 1 textview, or multiple views in the layout.
You will then need to add those views to your **StringHolder** class, and bind up the views like is already being done with holder.txtTitle.

Change the instantiation of the adapter to reference your custom layout:

```
new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.my_awesome_layout, addressList);
```

Edit: It would be a really good idea to have a read through [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) to familiarise yourself a little more with listviews.